# HTML Tidy fails on script tag in JavaScript string literal

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using HTML Tidy in PHP and it's producing unexpected results because of a `<script>` tag in a JavaScript string literal. Here's a sample input:

```
<html>
<script>
var t='<script><'+'/script>';
</script>
</html>
```

HTML Tidy's output:

```
<html>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var t='<script><'+'/script>';
<\/script>
<\/html>
//]]>
</script>
</html>
```

It's interpreting `</script></html>` as part of the script. Then, it adds another `</script></html>` to close the open tags. I tried this on an online version of HTML Tidy (http://www.dirtymarkup.com/) and it's producing the same error.

How do I prevent this error from occurring in PHP?

Comment: I would say "open a bug ticket", but they do not have any means to do so on their web site...

Comment: its an interesting bug but seems very specific to the close script </script> tag, I would just use your current solution.. also the use case for outputting the < and the /script> separately confuses me

Comment: can you specify why do you want to add script tag to a variable.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I'm parsing webpages and the authors of those webpages may want to do so.

Comment: It's not interpreting the close tags, but the opening `<script>` inside you JavaScript and tries to close that.

Comment: `var t='&lt;script&gt;&lt;'+'/script&gt;' depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Bug reports go here: http://sourceforge.net/p/tidy/bugs/
But it does not seem like they want to solve any of them. Sad :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After playing around with it a bit I discovered that one can use comment `//'<\/script>'` to confuse the algorithm in a way to prevent this bug from occurring:

```
<html>
<script>
var t='<script><'+'/script>'; //'<\/script>'
</script>
</html>
```

After clean-up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

<html>
<head>

   <script>
var t='<script><'+'/script>'; //'<\/script>'
   </script>

   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that as the clean-up algorithm looks through the codes and detects the string `<script>` twice, it looks for `</script>` immediately. And separting `<` with `/script>` makes the second `</script>` goes undetected, which is why it decided to add another `</script>` at the end of the codes and somehow also closed it with antoher `</html>`. (Poor design indeed!)

So I made a second assumption that there isn't an if-statement in the algorithm to determine if a `</scirpt>` is in a comment, and I was right! Having another string `<\/script>` as a javascript comment indeed makes the algorithm to think that there are two `</script>` in total.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for string concatenation to avoid the closing `</script>`. Simply escaping the `/` character is enough to "fool" the parsers in browsers and, it seems, HTML Tidy's parser as well:

```
<html>
<script>
var t='<script><\/script>';
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the script tag not a full word but a string concatenation

```
<html>
<script>
var t='<scr'+'ipt><'+'/script>';
</script>
</html>
```

Resulting cleaned code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <script>
var t='<scr'+'ipt><'+'/script>';
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better practice to create a script tag like this:
(this should also solve your tidy issues)

```
<script>
    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://myserver.com/file.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make it so tidy doesn't detect the script tag. The "cleanest" way I could come up with is to escape a character in the tag.

```
<html>
<script>
var t='<\script><'+'/script>';
</script>
</html>
```

so you could even do this, without having to break the string up as above:

```
var t='<\script></\script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

That just works as expected

```
<html>
    <script>
        var t='<'+'script><'+'/script>';
    </script>
</html>
```

By the way, string concatenation is not best way to create dynamically HTML to insert in page, look for document.createElement or even templates engines (handlebars.js is my favourite)