# Need a way to match these strings using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Is there a regular expression that can match any of the following?

- `'<'+'script>'`
- `'<s'+'cript>'`
- `'<script'+'>'`
- `'</'+'script>'`
- `'</scr'       +     'ipt>'`
- `'<script></scrip'+'t>'`
- `'<script type=text/javascript src="http://..."></scrip'+'t>'`

I need to do this because HTML Tidy is producing errors if I have these strings in the HTML. I want remove them using `preg_replace()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Tidy fails on script tag in Javascript string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029242/html-tidy-fails-on-script-tag-in-javascript-string-literal)

Comment: How about simply, `preg_replace("/'\s*\+\s*'/", "", $html);` ?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question - you can add a bounty to increase visibility if you haven't received a(n/ satisfactory) answer

Comment: These are very different questions. One asks if HTML Tidy has a built-in method to fix this and one is using string manipulation.

Comment: Sure, `/.*/` will match all of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, interesting, but i think a parser of sorts would be a more reliable solution.

the following regex is bit of an abomination but it'll match what you what:

```
'</?(?:'\+')?(?=s).+(?=c).(?=r).+(?=i).+(?=p).+(?=t).+>'
```

it will also match a variety of tags that you don't want, i leave that to you:

```
'<scdcdacacapt type=text/javascript src="http://..."></cdscdcss'+'t>'
```

this is because of the `javascript` string in the type attribute, so if you have the word `javascript` inside any tag it'll match :(

hopefully it's a starting point for you

Answer (score -1):

Use `'\x3cscript\x3e'` instead of `'&lt;script&gt;'`.